# Get text from div element and modify its integer part - Selenium Webdriver (Java)

Tags: java, html, selenium-webdriver

I'm writing test cases in java using Selenium, a part of my test case requires me to get text from div element and increment its integer part by 1, so that it can be used later for comparison.

for example,

```
<div id="some_id">#27</div>
```

If the text from div element is "#27" , i want to increment it to "#28"...

I have already written code for this, but its a little complicated, just wanted to know if there was a simpler way or inbuilt function to perform these type of actions..

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's nothing built into Selenium to do this for you.  The only way I know of, which is probably also your existing solution, is to execute javascript directly:

```
//...retrieve and increment current value...
JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
js.executeScript("document.getElementById('some_id').innerHTML="+incrementedValue);
```

I would advise that modifying the contents of the page is not really something you should do from a Selenium test, though.  See [How do I execute Javascript directly?](https://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/FrequentlyAskedQuestions#Q%3a_How_do_I_execute_Javascript_directly?)